# news site ranking

Tags: math, ranking

I'm building a news site in which the user can vote up or down articles. The articles are linked to different entities: person, place, company, ... The entities have a global score and a per user score.

So when a user votes up/down in an article, the linked entities global score and per user score changes.

For example: there's an article mentioning Google and Microsoft. User A likes the article and votes up. The global and user A scores of Google and Microsoft entities increases.

I'd like that user A has more impact on his personal scores and less impact on the global score.

Also the entities will have to start with some score in order that the first site users can't decrease it too much.

I'm thinking about ranking an entity from 0 to 1. The votes are binary: like(1), not like(0).

I'm looking at the [Bayesian average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_average) method mentioned in [this blog post](http://masanjin.net/blog/how-to-rank-products-based-on-user-input) with C=0.7 and with different values for m(I use a m for the personal score and another one for the general score). The tests I ran showed almost no difference between the personal and global scores. It seems I couldn't find the right values.

Edit:

This is the code(python) I'm using to calculate the bayesian. With this formula the results are better:

```
def bayesian_average(votes, C=100, m=0.7): #C higher for global
    #votes = [1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1]
    avg_votes = C
    avg_rating = m
    ent_votes = len(votes) #entity votes
    ent_rating = sum(votes) / float(ent_votes)
    ba = ( (avg_votes * avg_rating) + (ent_votes * ent_rating) ) / (avg_votes + ent_votes)
    return ba
```

Comment: Can you show what you've done so far? Your code will allow us to determine whether you've made an obvious mistake or not. I wonder if you've somehow used 0.7 as the pseudo-sample size rather than the target for the average (the prior mean in the Bayesian average)

Answer (score 2):

I now just go to [Evan Miller's home page](http://www.evanmiller.org/) when I want to do something like this. You probably want one (or more) of these three techniques:

- [How Not To Sort By Average Rating](http://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html)
- [Linear Regression For Fun And Profit](http://www.evanmiller.org/linear-regression-for-fun-and-profit.html)
- [Rank Hotness With Newton's Law of Cooling](http://www.evanmiller.org/rank-hotness-with-newtons-law-of-cooling.html)